# Playing mp3 on iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, sdk, audio, mp3, avaudioplayer

```
-(IBAction)musiconButtonClicked:(id)sender{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NextRevIt" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    [audioPlayer play];
}


-(IBAction)musicoffButtonClicked:(id)sender{
    [audioPlayer stop]; <----says this is undeclared?
}
```

I can get the audio to play fine, but how do i make a button that stops the audio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in your `interface` block in the `.h`.

```
AVAudioPlayer* audioPlayer;
```

You will need to check for an instance and release it as well.

Comment: don't forget to @syntheize it in the .m and dealloc it as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `AVAudioPlayer* audioPlayer` as a method local variable. Change the scope of that variable to class level. Follow *Daniel A. White's* suggestion